# Callback de SetTimeout() sincrona?

Tags: javascript

estoy recibiendo conexiones de usuarios a traves de socketIO. Por cada usuario que se loguea mando a llamar una funcion que pone en pantalla una etiqueta con el nombre del usuario logueado. esta en pantalla durante aprox 3 segundos y desaparece. todo funciona bien pero si dos usuarios se conectan al mismo tiempo se cambia el nombre de usuario en la etiqueta antes que termine el setTimeout como podria hacer que espere los 3 segundos y volver a llamar a la funcion para el proximo usuario? intente usar async await en todas las funciones intervinientes pero no me funciona o no supe como convinarlo, aqui esta el codigo:

```
const socket = io();
socket.emit('usuario', usuario.Nombre);
socket.on('logueado', (data) => {
  let usuarioLocal = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('usuario'));
  if(usuarioLocal.Rol == true)
  if(data != usuarioLocal.Nombre) loguedUser(data);
});

function loguedUser(data){
    let $tempo = document.querySelector('.loguedUser');
    $tempo.firstChild.textContent = data;
    $tempo.style.transform = "translateX(-299px)";
    setTimeout(() => {
      $tempo.style.transform = "translateX(0)";
    }, 2500);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una opción más viable es no usar un solo contenedor para todos los usuarios, sino un elemento para cada uno que, pasado el tiempo especificado, se va a eliminar. Lo mejor de todo, es que puedes animarlos desde CSS, sin Javascript.

```js
// Contenedor donde se van a mostrar todos los usuarios
let logged = document.querySelector('#logged-users');

// Función para agregar usuario conectado
function userLogged(user) {
    // Crear un div por cada usuario
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `El usuario <b>${user}</b> se ha conectado.`);
    logged.appendChild(div);
    // Eliminar después de 3 segundos
    setTimeout(function() {
        div.remove();
    }, 3000);
}

// Probando a agregar 3 usuarios

// Primer usuario
userLogged('Triby');
// Segundo usuario después de 1 segundo
setTimeout(function() {
    userLogged('Hernán García');
}, 1000);
// Tercer usuario
setTimeout(function() {
    userLogged('Stack Overflow');
}, 2000);
```

```css
#logged-users {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#logged-users > div {
    background: #ddd;
    border: 1px #777 solid;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 150px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    /* Mostar y ocultar con animación */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    /* Dura poco menos de 3 segundos, para no interferir con setTimeout */
    animation: user-animation 2.9s linear;
}

@keyframes user-animation {
    0% { margin-left: 150px; }
    15% { margin-left: 0; }
    85% { margin-left: 0; }
    100% { margin-left: 150px; }
}
```

```html
<div id="logged-users"></div>
```

Comment: la etiqueta la tengo fuera de pantalla y cada vez que se loguea un user entra desde la derecha, se mantiene 3 seg y se vuelve fuera de pantalla. No se si funcionaria de esta manera agregando varias,, pero seria cuestion de probar, muchas gracias!!

Comment: @HernánGarcia, precisamente, estaba editando la pregunta para agregar un ejemplo de animación cuando llegó tu comentario. Revisa la actualización.

Comment: pufff, increible!!, como siempre, mil gracias!!!