# ¿Cómo hago para que al enviar una notificación esta esté por encima del body?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nodejs

Cuando envío notificaciones con flash en nodejs, estas mueven el body hacia abajo, cómo hago o qué tengo que poner para que esto no estorbe y quede por así decirlo por encima del body.
Seguramente debe haber alguna etiqueta o algo que haga que no choque o moleste al resto del texto, pero no se me ocurre cómo buscarlo por la web, ni menos cómo hacerlo.
Para quitar la notificación se tiene que apretar el botón de la X.

Ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
    <symbol id="check-circle-fill" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zm-3.97-3.03a.75.75 0 0 0-1.08.022L7.477 9.417 5.384 7.323a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06 1.06L6.97 11.03a.75.75 0 0 0 1.079-.02l3.992-4.99a.75.75 0 0 0-.01-1.05z"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="info-fill" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8 16A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16zm.93-9.412-1 4.705c-.07.34.029.533.304.533.194 0 .487-.07.686-.246l-.088.416c-.287.346-.92.598-1.465.598-.703 0-1.002-.422-.808-1.319l.738-3.468c.064-.293.006-.399-.287-.47l-.451-.081.082-.381 2.29-.287zM8 5.5a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z"/>
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="exclamation-triangle-fill" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M8.982 1.566a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566zM8 5c.535 0 .954.462.9.995l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0L7.1 5.995A.905.905 0 0 1 8 5zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 1 0 2 1 1 0 0 1 0-2z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
{{#if success}}
    <div style="margin: 20px"></div>
    <div class="alert alert-success mx-auto" style="width: 300px; justify-content: center; font-size: large"
         role="alert">
        <svg class="bi flex-shrink-0 me-2" width="30" height="30" role="img" aria-label="Success:">
            <use xlink:href="#check-circle-fill"/>
        </svg>
        {{success}}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
                style="margin-left: 6px"></button>
    </div>
{{/if}}
{{#if error}}
    <div class="container">
        <div style="margin: 20px"></div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger mx-auto" style="width: fit-content; justify-content: center; font-size: large"
             role="alert">
            <svg class="bi flex-shrink-0 me-2" width="24" height="24" role="img" aria-label="Warning:">
                <use xlink:href="#exclamation-triangle-fill"/>
            </svg>
            {{error}}
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
                    style="margin-left: 6px"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Usa con contenedor con posición fija. Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/465968/54039) te pueda servir, solo adapta la posición donde quieres que aparezca la notificación.

Comment: o puedes usar Z-index

Answer (score 0):

Usa la propiedad [position: absolute](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) para sobre-ponerlo sobre los demás elementos, te dejo un [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) sobre mas información de como funcionan los 5 diferentes valores de la propiedad position

```css
.alert {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='alert' >
    soy una alerta sobrepuesta
  </div>
 texto de prueba
<div>
```

puedes usar la propiedad top del css para posicionar el div mas abajo

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).