# Como mostrar un div a la derecha de la pantalla cada que se reciba un socket js

Tags: javascript, java, html, socket

json:

```
[
    {
        "id": "234",
        "nombre": "manzana",
        "color": "rojo"
    },
    {
        "id": "334",
        "nombre": "pera",
        "color": "verde"
    }
]
```

Recibo un socket de la siguiente manera:

```
function connect() {
    username = obtieneUsuario();

    if (username) {

        var socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws");
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

        stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
    }
}


function onConnected() {
    // Subscribe to the Public Topic
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/public', onMessageReceived);

    // Tell your username to the server
    stompClient.send("/app/socket.register",
        {},
        JSON.stringify({ sender: username, type: 'JOIN' })
    )
}


function onError(error) {
    console.log('STOMP error ' + error);
}

function onMessageReceived(payload) {
    
    var message = JSON.parse(payload.body);

    if (message.type === 'JOIN') {

        message.content = message.sender + ' joined!';
        console.log(message.content);
        
        
    } else if (message.type === 'LEAVE') {

        message.content = message.sender + ' left!';
        console.log(message.content);
    } else {
        console.log(message.content);               
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    connect();
})
```

Como puedo mostrar el id del de cada fruta que reciba en el json arriba a la derecha sin que se encimen, y cada que se reciba un nuevo socket

O también quisiera saber como recorrer los items del json que recibo se que seria con un for pero al intentar recorrerlo me sale undefind lo hago así:

```
let(items of message.content){
    console.log(items.id)
}
```

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/465968/54039) hay un ejemplo para mostrar un bloque y ocultarlo después de cierto tiempo; puedes mostrar todos los que necesites.

Comment: Me ganaste de mano @Triby. Venia a mostrarle lo mismo, jaja